# Visual UML sequence diagram with easy insertion of new vertical/horizontal objects, no dragging around

Tags: gratis, open-source, gui, uml

I am looking for a tool to generate UML sequence diagrams:

[image: UML sequence diagram]

The main requirement is that **I don't want to move anything with the mouse**:

- The lifelines (vertical) and messages (horizontal) should be stacked to the left and top automatically.
- I should be able to add a new lifeline (or message) as easily as a column (or row) in a spreadsheet program, and the lifelines (or messages) at the right (or bottom) of it should be automatically pushed a bit further to make place for the new one.

Other requirements:

- Visually edit lifeline and message names
- Zero code writing, so tools like http://www.websequencediagrams.com are not OK
- Generates valid UML
- Free, ideally open source

Comment: Out of curiosity what program was used to create the UML sequence diagram you put in your question?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: This example is from Wikimedia Commons. I often use ArgoUML. I was using StarUML a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

The best I know of is Enterprise Architect (EA), now in version 14.1. Though it is cheap but not free. I am not familiar with newest versions of Papyrus or Rhapsody. They might come close. The use-cases of adding messages depends on what you want: insert, move around, add timing, push to a new sub-sequence, ... EA supports most of them.

Comment: Can you add a link? And add the actual price?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "move around"? Do you mean swapping two columns or rows? Or do you mean dragging an element around, for example a few pixels to the right, for aesthetics?

Comment: @JanDoggen: you may refer to the [tutorial](https://sparxsystems.com/resources/tutorials/uml2/sequence-diagram.html), also not all use-cases are mentioned. Also the uml-models.pdf found at the [resources page](https://sparxsystems.com/resources/user-guides/14.0/index.html#guidebooks) tells a lot about Messages. However, I did not find _Alt+Right Mouse Click_ to move messages around.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul:  two use-cases to distinct when editing a sequence diagram: move a message to get space above for more messages, or move a message for reordering. The first is done by just a selection, the latter by Alt+selection of the message.

Comment: I am looking for a tool where everything "*should be stacked to the left and top automatically*". That is the main requirement. If I understand correctly, to use EA that way I would have to remember to always press Alt when using the mouse.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, I do not think that simple statements fit. It's more diffentiated as you might think. EA - and others - are CAD tools for SW architecture (among others). As with other CAD tools (e.g. CATIA 5 for mechanical architecture) you need a level of experience, because they are complex.